# Can the product of two primes (a semiprime) have proper composite divisors?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**I am trying to prove the following proposition**:

Let $\;$ $m^{*}_{1} = m_{1} \cdot k$ $\;$ and $\;$ $m^{*}_{2} = m_{2} \cdot k$. $\;$ If $m_{1}$, $m_{2}$, and $k $ are primes distinct from each other, then $\gcd\,(\,m^{*}_{1}, m^{*}_{2}\,) = k$ .

**What I've tried:**

Proof. We assume $m_{1}$, $m_{2}$, and $k $ are primes.
By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, there is a unique way of factoring $m^{*}_{1}$ and $m^{*}_{2}$ as a product of primes. In our case, the factorizations are

- $m^{*}_{1} = m_{1} \cdot k, \,$ and
- $m^{*}_{2} = m_{2} \cdot k.$

To find $\gcd(\,m^{*}_{1}, m^{*}_{2}\,),$ we must consider **all** the divisors and, then, take the largest of them.

If we take for granted the **Lemma** "a product of two primes (a semiprime) does not have proper **composite** divisors",

then $m^{*}_{1}$ and $m^{*}_{2}$ do not have proper **composite** divisors.

Thus, the only proper divisors of  $m^{*}_{1}$ and $m^{*}_{2}$ are the prime ones and one itself:

- $1,$
- $m_{1}$,
- $m_{2}$, and
- $k$.

Therefore, the only proper **common** divisors of $m^{*}_{1}$ and $m^{*}_{2}$ are $1$ and $k$. Moreover, since $k$ is bigger than $1$, we can say that $k$ is the Greatest Common Divisor of $m^{*}_{1}$ and $m^{*}_{2}$. QED.

The thing is, I am not sure if the Lemma I mentioned is true and I need help proving it.

Thank you.

Comment: I would go for a proof by contradiction approach, rather than what you've got here.

Comment: But the product of two (not necessarily distinct) primes cannot have any composite **proper** divisors.

Comment: Since you know exactly the prime factorization of each number, you know exactly **all** of the divisors of each number. You can enumerate these explicitly and say which ones are common divisors. Then which one is greatest.

Comment: Prove that the divisors of $pq$ are precisely $1$, $p$, $q$, and $pq$, if $p$ and $q$ are prime.

Comment: @bof, I edited the Lemma so that it is clear that I am looking for divisors distinct from the product of the two primes.

Comment: @Geoffrey, that's what I am trying to prove.

Comment: @DavidK, I have the **prime** divisors of each number, but how can I prove that those are **all** the possible divisors?

Comment: @JesseElliott, I am trying but I'm stuck

Comment: The divisors of $n$ can easily be determined if the prime factorization of $n$ is known. And if $n=pq$ with DISTINCT primes $p,q$ , then , as mentioned , the divisors are exactly $1,p,q,pq$. This is because the prime factors of a divisor of $n$ must also be prime factors of $n$ and the corresponding exponent cannot exceed the exponent of the same prime factor, occuring in the factorization of $n$. If $n=p^2$ (the primes are equal), then we have divisors $1,p,p^2$.

Comment: So, in both cases, the proper divisors are obviously not composite (either prime or $1$). By the way , the product of two (possibly equal) primes is called a "semiprime".

Comment: @Peter, why the prime factors of a divisor of n must also be prime factors of n?

Comment: "By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, there is a unique way of factoring" 
After that that statement the proof should be two sentences at the *very* longest.
Something like: The only prime factors $m_1^*$ and $m_2^*$ have in common is $k$ and its only to a single power in either, so the unique prime factorization of the $\gcd$ is $k^1$.

  And the "Lemma" is just an *immediate* and consequence of FTA.  A semiprime is a product of two primes, by FTA, this is a unique prime factorization, so the only proper factors of the number are the two primes.  That's all.

Comment: "@Peter, why the prime factors of a divisor of n must also be prime factors of n?"  A divisor of a divisor must be a divisor.  If $a|b$ that means there is an integer $k$ so that $b=ak$.  And if $c|a$ then there is an integer, $m$ so that $a=cm$.  So $b = a(km)$ and $km$ is an integer so $c|b$.  So the primes that divide a divisor of $n$ must divide $n$ as well.

Comment: @fleablood I think the statement "The only prime factors $m^{∗}_{1}$ and $m^{∗}_{2}$ have in common is $k$" is not trivial by only looking at the FTA. This is because we could think that $m^{∗}_{1}$ and $m^{∗}_{2}$ have prime factors different from the ones that appear in the unique factorization. Namely, we could find a different prime factor which multiplied by a composite integer equals $m^{∗}_{1}$ or $m^{∗}_{2}$. So, I think the statement you made becomes trivial only after the "Lemma" is proved. I am not convinced by the proof you provided for the "Lemma" because of my previous argument.

Comment: @fleablood "why the prime factors of a divisor of n must also be prime factors of n?" thank you very much for the proof you provided for this statement.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your comments/ideas.

Based on them, I worked out a proof for the Lemma:

**Lemma**. The product of two primes (a semiprime) does not have proper composite divisors.

Proof. By contradiction.

Let $s = ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are primes. By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, $ab$ is the only way to write $s$ as a product of primes.

For the sake of contradiction, we assume there is a proper composite divisor $k$ of $s$. Since $k$ divides $s$, then $s = kk_{1}$ for some integer $k_{1}$. (Note that $k_{1}$ must be bigger than $1$ because $k$ is smaller than $s$).

By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, we can write $k$ as a unique product of primes $p_{1} \cdots p_{j} \,$ (note that $j \gt 1$ because $k$ is composite). Similarly, $k_{1}$ can be written as a unique product of primes $q_{1}\cdots q_{l} \,.$

Namely, $k$ can be written as the product of at least two primes and $k_{1}$ can be written as the product of at least one prime.

Therefore, since $s = kk_{1}$,$\,$ $s$ can be written as the product of at least three primes ($s = kk_{1} = p_{1}p_{2}q_{1}$). This contradicts the fact that $ab$ (the product of two primes) is the only way to write $s$ as a product of primes. Hence, our assumption that $s$ has a proper composite divisor is false. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Why do you need to prove $k_1$ is composite?  All you need is that it has a prime factor.  Also, you state that $s$ is a product of at least $4$ prime factors and then write it as a product of exactly four factors.

Comment: @MichaelBurr you're right, I'll fix it